# Username may contain lowercase characters and numbers

Tags: php, regex

I want to allow lowercase characters and numbers in username field.

But with following conditions...

- Only numbers as username **NOT allowed** (e.g. only mobile number)
- Only lowercase characters **allowed** (e.g. without any number in username)
- Lowercase characters **+** numbers allowed (e.g. combination of lowercase and numbers)
- Minimum length **8** characters required
- Maximum length **20** characters allowed

What php regex will do it ?

I tried with following, but it forces lowercase + numbers. Only lowercase username not allowing.

```
$username_pattern = '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-z0-9]{8,20}$/';
```

**I want only lowercase and/or lowercase+numbers ( min 8 and max 20 ) in username**

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify it to not allowing only digits

```
^(?!\d*$)[a-z0-9]{8,20}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!\d*$)` Negative lookahead, assert not only digits till end of string
- `[a-z0-9]{8,20}` Match 8-20 times a char a-z or a digit 0-9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bYVi1m/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/7em2P)

```
$username_pattern = '/^(?!\d*$)[a-z0-9]{8,20}$/';
$userNames = [
    "1a3b5678",
    "1a3b5678abcd",
    "12345678",
    "1a3b5678abcddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd",
    "1a3B5678",
    "a1"
];

foreach ($userNames as $userName) {
    if (preg_match($username_pattern, $userName)) {
        echo "Match - $userName" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "No match - $userName" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output

```
Match - 1a3b5678
Match - 1a3b5678abcd
No match - 12345678
No match - 1a3b5678abcddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
No match - 1a3B5678
No match - a1
```

Comment: I tried... but it is allowing Uppercase characters... I want only lowercase and/or lowercase+numbers

Comment: @VMJCreations It does not allow uppercase characters. See https://regex101.com/r/ZCTxJ7/1

Comment: how can we check for spaces and deny spaces ?

Comment: @VMJCreations This pattern `[a-z0-9]{8,20}$` does not allow spaces, only chars in range a-z and digits in range 0-9